# Is it possible to add on to an existing Doctrine Query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I've built a page in Symfony, which utilises the Doctrine Query Builder to return results. The page also integrates search functionality. The page works fine at the minute, but I'm wondering if the Doctrine Query Builder section of my code can be re-factored?

So my question is, rather than copying and pasting the same query (as I have done so below in my code ($results)) and adding additional 'where' and 'setParameter' methods to the query builder, is it possible to just append the additional options to the first query so that I don't have to re-use code?

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('managerName');
$results = $em->createQueryBuilder()
       ->select('d.name','d.createdAt')
       ->from('ManagerName:Demo', 'd')
       ->orderBy('d.name')
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('managerName');
        $results = $em->createQueryBuilder()
              ->select('d.name', 'd.createdAt')
              ->from('ManagerName:Demo', 'd')
              ->where('d.name LIKE :searchTerm')
              ->orderBy('d.name')
              ->setParameter('searchTerm', '%' . $search->getSearch() . '%')
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
            return $this->render('AcmeBundleName:Demo:index.html.twig', [
                "form" => $form->createView(),
                "results" => $results,
                "search" => $search->getSearch(),
            ]);
        }
    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
}
```

So an example of what I'm looking for/trying to get at would be like the following:

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('managerName');

$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
       ->select('d.name','d.createdAt')
       ->from('ManagerName:Demo', 'd')
       ->orderBy('d.name')
       ->getQuery();

$results = $query->getResult();

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('managerName');

        $results = $query->where('d.name LIKE :searchTerm')
               ->setParameter('searchTerm', '%' . $search->getSearch() . '%');

        return $this->render('AcmeBundleName:Demo:index.html.twig', [
                "form" => $form->createView(),
                "results" => $results,
                "search" => $search->getSearch(),
            ]);
    }
    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
}
```

I've no idea if its possible to extend the query I've previously built and Googling for hours on end doesn't seem to return any useful sources I can relate to.

I've also looked through plenty of Doctrine documentation, including the following without success: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: After the first declaration of `$results`, the variable is never used. Is it used in some code not shown here?

Comment: I eventually pass it through as a parameter when rendering the page, but seeing as I'm more interested in re-factoring my code and the current code works, I haven't included all of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to call `getQuery()` only when you perform the request:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('managerName');

$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('d.name','d.createdAt')
        ->from('ManagerName:Demo', 'd')
        ->orderBy('d.name');

$results = $query
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                
        $results = $query->where('d.name LIKE :searchTerm')
                ->setParameter('searchTerm', '%' . $search->getSearch() . '%')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

        return $this->render('AcmeBundleName:Demo:index.html.twig', [
            "form" => $form->createView(),
            "results" => $results,
            "search" => $search->getSearch(),
        ]);
    }
    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
}
```

`$query` is an instance of `\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder` and you can call `where()`, etc. on this object.

Then you need to call `$query->getQuery()->getResult();` to perform the query.

Note that I also remove this duplicated line:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('managerName');
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for this. I knew it would be something simple, but nothing I tried seemed to work! Friday afternoons ey...

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.  If you seperate the querybuilder object this is fairly trivial.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('d.name','d.createdAt')
        ->from('ManagerName:Demo', 'd')
        ->orderBy('d.name');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
```